# Fan not recognized on an HP nc6400

Tags: fan, overheating

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 and an HP nc6400 laptop, and it doesn't recognize my fans, which means that my laptop keeps overheating, is there anyway to make it recognize them? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3):

Try to setup LM-sensors and fancontrol, then do the following:

`sudo pwmconfig`

There you can make some configuration and see whether the fans are detected correctly. However, this requires that the sensors kernel module is installed.

1. Install lm-sensors using apt-get or the Synaptic GUI.

`sudo apt-get install lm-sensors`

1. Run the mkdev.sh script in the lm-sensors source.

It is exacted below:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2780

Comment: How do I run LM-Sensors and fancontrol?